# Unable to resolve module `../screens/maparea/index`

Tags: react-native

[fatal][tid:main] Unable to resolve module `../screens/maparea/index` from `somePath`: could not resolve `somePath' as a file nor as a folder.

How should I approach to solve this kind of error?
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Ij3.png]

Answer (score 0):

i think the directory you are given is not correct.
 try providing ./index or ./screens/maparea/index

Answer (score 0):

It is because of incorrect file paths or the `index.js` file has not been exported properly.